# $‎\sigma(a)=‎\sigma‎(b)‎$‎‎, ‎‎if ‎‎‎$‎a,b$‎ ‎‎are unitarily equivalent

Tags: operator-theory, banach-algebras

‎Let ‎$‎A$ be a *-algebra and ‎$‎a,b$ are ‎unitaril‎y equivalent ‎in ‎‎$‎A$ ( i.e. there exists a unitary ‎$‎u$ of ‎$‎A$ s.t ‎$b=uau^{*‎}‎$ ‎‎).‎
‎I ‎want ‎to ‎prove ‎that ‎‎‎‎‎$‎\sigma(a)=‎\sigma‎(b)‎$‎‎, ‎‎if ‎‎‎$‎a,b$‎ ‎‎are unitarily equivalent.‎

Also, I know that if ‎$‎A$ is unital and ‎$‎u$‎‎‎‎ is a unitary element in ‎$‎A$ ‎(‎i.e. ‎$uu^{*}=u^{*}u=1$‎)‎, then ‎‎‎

$Ad~u:A\rightarrow A~,~a\mapsto~uau^{*}$‎‎ ‎

is ‎an ‎*-automorphism ‎of ‎‎$‎A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ and $v$ are elements of an algebra with identity $1$ and $v$ is invertible, then $x$ is invertible if and only if $vxv^{-1}$ is invertible.  If $x^{-1}$ exists, then $(vxv^{-1})^{-1}=vx^{-1}v^{-1}$.  The other direction follows because $x=v^{-1}(vxv^{-1})v$.  (It could also be noted that $y\mapsto vyv^{-1}$ is an algebra isomorphism.)

Apply this with $x=a-\lambda 1$ and $v=u$ to see what happens.